# Drupal - The directory sites/default/files exists but is not writable and could not be made writable

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, file-permissions, file-ownership

When I try to add "**Public file system path**" and "**Private file system path**" in ***Administration > Configuration > Media > File System*** in my drupal site, I get "*The directory sites/default/files exists but is not writable and could not be made writable*" Error. But it is working fine in localhost.

The permission for the folders is 755, I changed it to 777. But still it didnt work.

I also changed the owner following some blogs using:
*chown -R apache:apache private*

But it didnt help either.

Please Help. 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Use "chmod -R 777" command to give default folder write permission. If you are not the super user then append sudo keyword

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki Yes I did, but no luck.

Comment: what is your operating system ubuntu, windows or what

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki it is centos

Comment: Try this command chmod a+w sites/default 
Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-drupal-on-a-virtual-server-running-centos-6--2

Comment: I have set folder permissions to 777, But still I get same error.

Comment: Hi, try this command chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/drupal
Source: https://www.howtoforge.com/centos-7-drupal-installation

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace .htaccess in sites/default/files with the original one or

try to remove .htaccess in sites/default/files or

try to change .htaccess in sites/default/files from
    
    `Options None
    Options +FollowSymLinks`
    
to
    
    `#Options None
    #Options +FollowSymLinks`

You could try same with .htaccess in Drupal root

Comment: adding # unfortunately didn't helped me

Answer (score 1):

I am too late for this answer but may help someone who searches for it.

If SELinux security is enabled and there is not a "rw" in the context for the files/ directory it will not be writable no matter which group, user, or Unix permissions are granted.

To see these "hidden" settings:

```
ls -laZ sites/default

drwxr-sr-x. apache www unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. apache www unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ..
-rwxr-sr-x. apache www unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0         default.settings.php
drwxrwsr-x. apache www unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 files
-rwxr-sr-x. apache www unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 settings.php
```

To change the settings on files/ so it is writable:

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t files
```

When the install is done reset the context using the same command with the original "http_sys_content_t" context.

FYI - This command will also be necessary to enable writes when installing themes under the "all" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to run restorecon on the directory
for eg:

```
restorecon -rv default/
```

Answer (score 0):

chmod -R 777 sites/default/files/

^ worked for me, however I had no private file system path.